# Erro de denied ao conectar spring boot ao mysql

Tags: java, spring, spring-boot, flyway

Estou tentando me conectar com o mysql mas só esse erro:

### Caused by: org.flywaydb.core.internal.exception.FlywaySqlException: Unable to obtain connection from database: Access denied for user ''@'localhost' (using password: NO)

```
SQL State  : 28000
Error Code : 1045
Message    : Access denied for user ''@'localhost' (using password: NO)
```

Jás estou horas tentando resolver mas não estou conseguindo. Pq?

No arquivo application.properties

```
spring.datasource.url=jdbc:mysql://localhost/teste?createDatabaseIfNotExist=true&useSSL=false


spring.datasource.data-username=root
spring.datasource.data-password=1234
```

Answer (score 1):

O problema, aparentemente, é que você está definindo o login apenas para os scripts de DML, como correção deveria adicionar os dados de login no DB default, além disto você preci sa definir as propriedades `hibernate.dialect` e `ddl-auto` e, por fim, adicione `&allowPublicKeyRetrieval=true` na url do DB:

```
# URL para DB
spring.datasource.url=jdbc:mysql://localhost/teste?createDatabaseIfNotExist=true&useSSL=false&allowPublicKeyRetrieval=true

# Dados default de acesso para ao DB
spring.datasource.username  = root
spring.datasource.password  = 1234

# Dados para execuçao de scripts DML
# Somente é necessario se for diferente dos dados default
spring.datasource.data-username  = root
spring.datasource.data-password  = 1234

# Caso queria definir dados de login para execuçao de scripts DDL
# Assim como data-username somente é necessario se for diferente dos dados default
# spring.datasource.schema-username  = root
# spring.datasource.schema-password  = 1234

# The SQL dialect makes Hibernate generate better SQL for the chosen database
spring.jpa.properties.hibernate.dialect = org.hibernate.dialect.MySQL5Dialect

# Hibernate ddl auto (create, create-drop, validate, update)
spring.jpa.hibernate.ddl-auto = update


spring.jpa.properties.hibernate.jdbc.lob.non_contextual_creation=true
```